Manga about this girl who was murdered and was reborn as a princess
I remember this from 7th grade (2020). It's about this girl who was murdered and was reborn as a princess in this family. All the guys had powers, so they were like the big people. She had this brother who did fighting rings in arenas, but in disguise. She also had another brother who was older and was sent to go to war. I believe she’d write to him.
The king didn’t like her for the longest time because he wanted a son. But after a while he slowly warmed up and started protecting her. I think she was going to get married off, but the dude didn't like her, but then he slowly did.

For those of us in the rest of the world, US 7th grade is age approximately 12 years.

Do you recall the hair colour of the female lead?

It was brown I’m pretty sure

Was this in full color or black and white? Can you clarify the characters' relationships? The king disliked his daughter because he wanted a son, but she has multiple brothers? Is "the dude" in the last sentence her fiance? Was she murdered and reborn in the same world, or murdered in our world and reborn in a fantasy world? Or specifically the world of a game or book?

You could improve this question by going through the checklists here and here and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

This is They Say I Was Born a King's Daughter. It is licensed by Tapas.

A murder victim is reborn, fully conscious of her past life, as a king’s unwanted daughter in a new world where despite the end of all wars and advancement of science, misogyny reigns.

The protagonist is murdered by a stalker in the first chapter and reborn as a baby princess in another world. The world is a mix of modern technology and older feudal class structure. Her father the king exclusively wants sons, and berates her mother after she is born.

She has multiple siblings from at least one other mother, including 3 half-brothers that are her "primary" siblings from skimming through the chapters. They show varying amounts of interest in her and bully/take advantage of her, e.g. taking her food away. Her caretakers are more than happy to focus on the boys instead of the infant girl.

She eventually wins them over, including her father with a combination of playing dumb/cute, genuine ability, and affection.
The arena scene first takes place in chapter 31; it may be re-appear later. To impress the protagonist, one of her brothers abruptly joins an arena ("stadium") fight with a mask on and defeats the reigning champion.


Into the Light Once Again.
This must be it, there was a previous question that was already answered, this sounds exactly like the story you describe.
